# Having trouble setting an element's onclick attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few elements on my webpage that share the class name "table-data". I am trying to loop through them and give each one of them a unique id, then I want all them to have the same onclick attribute. I was able to successfully give each one of them a unique id with pure JavaScript, but the part that I am having trouble with is giving them all the same onclick attribute. I tried with JavaScript and jQuery and failed using both.

Here is my code:

```js
// this counter will be used to give each element a unique id
var counter = 0;

// x holds all elements with the class name "table-data"
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("table-data");

    // loop through all the elements in the array x
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    // give each element the name "idNum" plus whatever number the counter variable holds
    var idName = 'idNum' + String(counter);

    // set the id name to the variable defined above
    x[i].setAttribute('id', idName);

    // here is the part I am struggling with, this section is supposed to alert the id of the element when it is clicked
    $('#' + idName).click(function () {
        alert(idName);
    });

    // increment the counter
    counter += 1;
```

The problem I am having is that all elements are showing the idName of the last element in the array "x". so if there are 5 elements in total and I run this code on them, they will all show the idName of the 5th element when clicked. I tried to alert() the idName outside of the onclick function and make it so the loop will alert the idName of each element as soon as it is assigned and that worked just fine. I would get five different ids for five different elements, so what is causing the problem inside the onclick function?

I also tried the following and it didn't work either:

```js
x[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'call_alert(this.idName)');

function call_alert(clickedId) {
    alert(clickedId);
}
```

I am very new to web programming so I am sorry if there are any obvious mistakes in my code.

Comment: use [`.click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) or .[`on('click'`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) not `setAttribute`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You won't need `counter` variable as you're already `i`:

```js
//var counter = 0;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("table-data");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  var idName = 'idNum' + String(i);
  x[i].setAttribute('id', idName);
  x[i].onclick = function() {
    console.log(this.id);
  }
  //counter += 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-data">table1</div>
<div class="table-data">table2</div>
<div class="table-data">table3</div>
<div class="table-data">table4</div>
<div class="table-data">table5</div>
<div class="table-data">table6</div>
```

---

jQuery version:

```js
$(".table-data").each((idx, element) => {
  $(element).attr("id", "idNum" + String(idx));
  $(element).on("click", () => {
    console.log($(element).attr("id"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-data">table1</div>
<div class="table-data">table2</div>
<div class="table-data">table3</div>
<div class="table-data">table4</div>
<div class="table-data">table5</div>
<div class="table-data">table6</div>
```

Comment: Sorry it wasn't me, I can't vote since I still don't have 15 reputation points, but your answer was very helpful :)

Comment: Well the way I got it to work was by using a combination of your answer and Liam's answer, but since Liam had more upvotes and your answer got downvoted I figured I would put the accept on yours :)

Answer (score 2):

You're making this much more complicated than your need to. You don't need to add an id to every element, you can simply bind on a class using the [class(`.`) selector](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and then add the click binding all in one go:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //match on the class
  $('.table-data').click(function(){
    //access the actual element clicked using $(this)
    alert('clicked'+ $(this).text());
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="table-data">1</a>
<a href="#" class="table-data">2</a>
```